# How to speed-up path lookup for large number of nodes?

Tags: mysql, drupal, query-optimization, pathauto

After I generated 34000 url aliases for all the nodes on Drupal 6 site, using pathauto, the site started to work really slow, every page loads more than 2 seconds. I'd really want my site to be search-engines-friendly, so it would be much better if every node had it's own URL, based on its title. Is there any way to speed up drupal page alias lookup? I tried creating indexes for all fields on table `url_alias`, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?  I'm getting about 115 url_alias queries per page load and even with path caching it generally adds up to about .5 seconds per page load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [Pressflow](http://pressflow.org/) or this patch http://drupal.org/node/456824